# How to hint many-to-many join in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2016, many-to-many, cardinality-estimates

I have 3 "large" tables that join on a pair of columns (both `int`s).

- Table1 has ~200 million rows
- Table2 has ~1.5 million rows
- Table3 has ~6 million rows

Each table has a clustered index on `Key1`, `Key2`, and then one more column. `Key1` has low cardinality and is very skewed. It is always referenced in the `WHERE` clause. `Key2` is never mentioned in the `WHERE` clause. Each join is many-to-many.

The problem is with cardinality estimation. The output estimation of each join gets *smaller* instead of *larger*. This results in final estimates of low hundreds when the actual result is well into the millions.

Is there any way for me to clue the CE into making better estimates?

```
SELECT 1
FROM Table1 t1
     JOIN Table2 t2
       ON t1.Key1 = t2.Key1
          AND t1.Key2 = t2.Key2
     JOIN Table3 t3
       ON t1.Key1 = t3.Key1
          AND t1.Key2 = t3.Key2
WHERE t1.Key1 = 1;
```

Solutions I have tried:

- Creating multi-column stats on `Key1`, `Key2`
- Creating *tons* of filtered stats on `Key1` (This helps quite a bit, but I end up with thousands of user-created stats in the database.)

[Masked execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkIRznRhZ) (sorry for the bad masking)

In the case I'm looking at, the result has 9 million rows. The new CE estimates 180 rows; the legacy CE estimates 6100 rows.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table1, #Table2, #Table3;
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Key1 INT NOT NULL, Key2 INT NOT NULL, T1Key3 INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_t1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Key1, Key2, T1Key3));
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (Key1 INT NOT NULL, Key2 INT NOT NULL, T2Key3 INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_t2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Key1, Key2, T2Key3));
CREATE TABLE #Table3 (Key1 INT NOT NULL, Key2 INT NOT NULL, T3Key3 INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_t3 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Key1, Key2, T3Key3));

-- Table1 
WITH Numbers
     AS (SELECT TOP (1000000) Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.number)
         FROM master..spt_values t1
              CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2),
     DataSize (Key1, NumberOfRows)
     AS (SELECT 1, 2000 UNION
         SELECT 2, 10000 UNION
         SELECT 3, 25000 UNION
         SELECT 4, 50000 UNION
         SELECT 5, 200000)
INSERT INTO #Table1
SELECT Key1
     , Key2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key1, T1Key3 ORDER BY Number)
     , T1Key3
FROM DataSize
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(NumberOfRows) 
                         Number
                       , T1Key3 = Number%(Key1*Key1) + 1 
                  FROM Numbers
                  ORDER BY Number) size;

-- Table2 (same Key1, Key2 values; smaller number of distinct third Key)
WITH Numbers
     AS (SELECT TOP (1000000) Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.number)
         FROM master..spt_values t1
              CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2)
INSERT INTO #Table2
SELECT DISTINCT 
       Key1
     , Key2
     , T2Key3
FROM #Table1
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (Key1*10) 
                         T2Key3 = Number
                  FROM Numbers
                  ORDER BY Number) size;

-- Table2 (same Key1, Key2 values; smallest number of distinct third Key)
WITH Numbers
     AS (SELECT TOP (1000000) Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.number)
         FROM master..spt_values t1
              CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2)
INSERT INTO #Table3
SELECT DISTINCT 
       Key1
     , Key2
     , T3Key3
FROM #Table1
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (Key1) 
                         T3Key3 = Number
                  FROM Numbers
                  ORDER BY Number) size;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #a;
SELECT col = 1 
INTO #a
FROM #Table1 t1
     JOIN #Table2 t2
       ON t1.Key1 = t2.Key1
          AND t1.Key2 = t2.Key2
WHERE t1.Key1 = 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #b;
SELECT col = 1 
INTO #b
FROM #Table1 t1
     JOIN #Table2 t2
       ON t1.Key1 = t2.Key1
          AND t1.Key2 = t2.Key2
     JOIN #Table3 t3
       ON t1.Key1 = t3.Key1
          AND t1.Key2 = t3.Key2
WHERE t1.Key1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to be clear, the optimizer already knows that it's a many-to-many join. If you force merge joins and look at an estimated plan you can see a property for the join operator which tells you if the join could be many-to-many. The problem that you need to solve here is bumping up the cardinality estimates, presumably so you get a more efficient query plan for the part of the query that you left out.

The first thing that I would try is putting the results of the join from `Object3` and `Object5` into a temp table. For the plan that you posted it's just a single column on 51393 rows, so it should hardly take up any space in tempdb. You can gather full stats on the temp table and that alone might be enough to get a sufficient accurate final cardinality estimate. Gathering full stats on `Object1` may help as well. Cardinality estimates often get worse as you traverse from a plan from right to left.

If that doesn't work you can try the `ENABLE_QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES` query hint if you don't already have it enabled at the database or server level. Microsoft locks plan-affecting performance fixes for SQL Server 2016 behind that setting. Some of them relate to cardinality estimates, so perhaps you'll get lucky and one of the fixes will help with your query. You can also try using the legacy cardinality estimator with a `FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION` query hint. Certain data sets may get better estimates with the legacy CE.

As a last resort you can manually increase the cardinality estimate by whatever factor you like using Adam Machanic's `MANY()` function. I talk about it in another [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168726/sql-server-cardinality-hint/168771#168771) but it looks like the link is dead. If you're interested I can try to dig something up.

Comment: Adam's `make_parallel` function gets used to help mitigate the problem. I'll have a look at `many`. Seems like a pretty gross band-aid.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server statistics only contain a histogram for the leading column of the statistics object. Therefore, you could create filtered stats that provide a histogram of values for `Key2`, but only among rows with `Key1 = 1`. Creating these filtered statistics on each table fixes the estimates and leads to the behavior you expect for the test query: each new join does not impact the final cardinality estimate (confirmed in both SQL 2016 SP1 and SQL 2017).

```
-- Note: Add "WITH FULLSCAN" to each if you want a perfect 20,000 row estimate
CREATE STATISTICS st_#Table1 ON #Table1 (Key2) WHERE Key1 = 1
CREATE STATISTICS st_#Table2 ON #Table2 (Key2) WHERE Key1 = 1
CREATE STATISTICS st_#Table3 ON #Table3 (Key2) WHERE Key1 = 1
```

Without these filtered statistics, SQL Server will take a more heuristic-based approach to estimating the cardinality of your join. The following whitepaper contains good high-level descriptions of some of the heuristics that SQL Server uses: [Optimizing Your Query Plans with the SQL Server 2014 Cardinality Estimator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn673537.aspx).

For example, adding the `USE HINT('ASSUME_JOIN_PREDICATE_DEPENDS_ON_FILTERS')` hint to your query will change the join containment heuristic to assume some correlation (rather than independence) between the `Key1` predicate and the `Key2` join predicate, which may be beneficial to your query. For the final test query, this hint increases the cardinality estimate from `1,175` to `7,551`, but is still quite a bit shy of the correct `20,000` row estimate produced with the filtered statistics.

Another approach we've used in similar situations is to extract the relevant subset of the data into #temp tables. Especially now that newer versions of SQL Server [no longer eagerly write #temp tables to disk](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/04/memory-ssd-tempdb-temp-table-sql-2014/), we've had good results with this approach. Your description of your many-to-many join implies that each individual #temp table in your case would be relatively small (or at least smaller than the final result set), so this approach might be worth trying.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table1_extract, #Table2_extract, #Table3_extract, #c
-- Extract only the subset of rows that match the filter predicate
-- (Or better yet, extract only the subset of columns you need!)
SELECT * INTO #Table1_extract FROM #Table1 WHERE Key1 = 1
SELECT * INTO #Table2_extract FROM #Table2 WHERE Key1 = 1
SELECT * INTO #Table3_extract FROM #Table3 WHERE Key1 = 1
-- Now perform the join on those extracts, removing the filter predicate
SELECT col = 1
INTO #c 
FROM #Table1_extract t1
JOIN #Table2_extract t2
    ON t1.Key2 = t2.Key2
JOIN #Table3_extract t3
    ON t1.Key2 = t3.Key2
```

Comment: We use filtered statistics extensively, but we make them one per `Key1` value on each table. We now have thousands of them.

Comment: @StevenHibble Good point that thousands of filtered stats could make management difficult. (We've also seen that it negatively impacts plan compilation time.) It might not fit your use case, but I also added another #temp table approach that we've used successfully several times.

Answer (score -1):

A reach.   No real basis other than try.

```
SELECT 1
FROM Table1 t1
     JOIN Table2 t2
       ON t1.Key2 = t2.Key2
      AND t1.Key1 = 1
      AND t2.Key1 = 1
     JOIN Table3 t3
       ON t2.Key2 = t3.Key2
      AND t3.Key1 = 1;
```