# how to override a table's cardinality or statistics histogram

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan, statistics

I remember reading once that it is possible to force SQL Server to assume a table is a certain size, or perhaps even override a statistics histogram, when compiling a query.  Can someone explain how to do that, if it's possible?

To be clear: the purpose of this is to do what-if scenario analysis, outside of production, when writing queries.  **I am not talking about modifying the query itself or using query hints.**  (Examples of modifying the query and using query hints can be found in the answers to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168726/sql-server-cardinality-hint).)

Comment: Have a look here [updating statistics using STATS_STREAM or WITH FULLSCAN?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/235517/updating-statistics-using-stats-stream-or-with-fullscan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `UPDATE STATISTICS`  WITH `ROWCOUNT` and `PAGECOUNT` option

See here some examples :
 https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2870/using-with-rowcount-and-pagecount-option-of-sql-server-update-statistics/
or
https://sqlsunday.com/2016/02/27/update-statistics-with-rowcount/